# find fieldset legend text that contains anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a question. Let say I have something like this:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>I am legend</legend>
<p>I am a paragraph</p>
<a href="#">I am an anchor</a>
</fieldset>
```

How do I get the text of the legend element in that fieldset when I click on the link?

Note: the format above could vary, I could have for example tables inside that fieldset, more paragraphs, etc...

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Basically go up until you hit the field set tag, then find the legend tag in its children, that way even if the link is embedded, or embedded field sets, it'll find the right one.

```
$('fieldset a').click(function(e){ 
    alert( $(this).closest('fieldset').children('legend:first').text() );
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```